# Capturing part of a group

Tags: c#, regex

I want to capture only digits in a string like this - $235,993.84. So that when i access my group it would return 23599384.

```
\$(?<amount>\d*,\d{3}\.\d{2})
```

Comment: Replace all non-digit chars by nothing?

Comment: Note that `[0-9]` is more appropriate than `\d` since it contains only ascii digits.

Comment: If my or `Ksv3n`'s answer helped, please acppet the best one

Comment: Thing is, this pattern is just one of many which i have in an array. There is already method made which handles captured groups. I can add exception for this pattern and remake these methods but it dont want to. Id rather use have regex to handle this if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
Regex.Replace(foo, "[^0-9]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making a capture, you can use `Regex.Replace` and replace non-digits by `String.Empty` :

```
  string input = " $235,993.84";
  string replacement = "";
  Regex rgx = new Regex("[^0-9]");
  string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);

  // result now contains 23599384
```

Answer (score 1):

For this example you shouldnt need Regex:

```
string test = "$235,993.84";
string onlyNums = new string(test.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
```